# How to write a specification of a method that char array convert to an integer in dafny?

Tags: specifications, dafny

```
method atoi(a:array<char>) returns(r:int)
requires a.Length>0
requires forall k :: 0<= k <a.Length ==> (a[k] as int) - ('0' as int) <= 9
ensures ??
{
    var j:int := 0;
    while j < a.Length
        invariant ??
    {
        r := r*10 + (a[j] as int) - ('0' as int);
        j := j + 1;
    }
}
```

How to write  "ensures" for the atoi  method and "invariant" for the while loops in dafny?

I express the idea "each bit of the return value corresponds to each bit of the character array" as following:

```
// Ten to the NTH power
// e.g.: ten_pos_pow(2) == 10*10 == 100
function ten_pos_pow(p:int):int
requires p>=0
ensures ten_pos_pow(p) >= 1
{
    if p==0 then 1 else
    10*ten_pos_pow(p-1)
}

// Count from right to left, the ith digit of integer v (i starts from zero)
// e.g.: num_in_int(123,0) == 3  num_in_int(123,1) == 2 num_in_int(123,2) == 1 
function num_in_int(v:int,i:int) : int
requires i>=0
{
    (v % ten_pos_pow(i+1))/ten_pos_pow(i)
}


method atoi(a:array<char>) returns(r:int)
requires a.Length>0
requires forall k :: 0<= k <a.Length ==> (a[k] as int) - ('0' as int) <= 9
ensures forall k :: 0<= k < a.Length ==> ((a[k] as int) - ('0' as int)) == num_in_int(r,a.Length-k-1)
{
    var i:int := 0;
    r := 0;
    while i < a.Length
       invariant 0<= i <= a.Length
       invariant forall k :: 0<= k < i ==> ((a[k] as int) - ('0' as int)) == num_in_int(r,i-k-1) // loop invariant violation
    {
        r := r*10 + (a[i] as int) - ('0' as int);
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

But the loops invariant violation. How to write a correct and provable specification?

Comment: what have you tried to do?

Comment: I tried to write an invariant: each bit of the return value corresponds to each bit of the character array. For example: if the char array is {'1','2','3'} and the return value is 123; then a[0] - '0' ==123%1000/100 and a[1]-'0' == 123%100/10  and a[2] - '0' == 123%10/1.

Comment: I want to find a proveable ralation ship (a specification for the atoi method) between the input char array and the integer result.

Comment: I like your idea "each bit of the return value corresponds to each bit of the character array". how did you express that in Dafny?

Comment: I express the idea in the update version, but I cannot write a correct loop invariant.